# ethers.js Contract object gets error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethers.js

I hope someone can enlighten me. I have a website with a button which should create a new Contract object of my token contract via the ethers.js library. I successfully connected my metamask with the website but when I click the button there is an error message like this:

```
ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at new Interface (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:199125)
    at BaseContract.getInterface (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:321623)
    at Contract.BaseContract (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:317578)
    at new Contract (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:329138)
    at buyTicket ((index):707:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):274:91)
```

This is my button code

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="buyTicket" onclick="buyTicket()">
    Buy Ticket
</button>
```

And this is my JavaScript section at the bottom of my html.file

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js@9.0.2/bignumber.min.js'></script>
<!--<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.7.3/web3.min.js'></script>-->
<script src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"
type="application/javascript">
</script>

<script>
    
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
    provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    //let tokenContractAddress = "0xf209CE1960Fb7E750ff30Ba7794ea11C6Acdc1f3";
    let tokenContractAddress = "0xb37f4a11045FB48A89fb4930C72481fce9942E07";
    let lotteryContractAddress = "0x3E03D4595b164F5C2098a5D154d7f2Bf516ba102";
    // Use BigNumber
    let decimals = BigInt(18);
    let amount = BigInt(5);
    const tokenABI = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": false,
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "from",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": false,
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "owner",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "account",
            "type": "address"
        }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint8",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint8"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "subtractedValue",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "decreaseAllowance",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "spender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "addedValue",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "increaseAllowance",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "recipient",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "sender",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "address",
            "name": "recipient",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
        }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
    ];
    
    
    function buyTicket(lotteryContractAddress, tokenContractAddress, amount, tokenABI, provider) {
        const tokenInstance = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, tokenABI, provider);
        

    }
    
    
</script>
```

After that I want to interact with that Contract instance, but I am not able to create it and don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: I already figured out that i can create the tokenInstance when i take the following line out of the buyTicket() function. The problem is, that i do only want to create it when i click the button. So does anyone know why i can not create the object instance inside the funktion? const tokenInstance = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, tokenABI, provider);

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it. I simply had to put the whole thing into the function section so that the variables were created after pushing the button. So this is the working code, i hope that helps someone fixing the same error faster than me :-)

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js@9.0.2/bignumber.min.js'></script>
<!--<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.7.3/web3.min.js'></script>-->
<script src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"
type="application/javascript">
</script>

<script>

    function buyTicket() {

        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        //let tokenContractAddress = "0xf209CE1960Fb7E750ff30Ba7794ea11C6Acdc1f3";
        let tokenContractAddress = "0xb37f4a11045FB48A89fb4930C72481fce9942E07";
        let lotteryContractAddress = "0x3E03D4595b164F5C2098a5D154d7f2Bf516ba102";
        // Use BigNumber
        let decimals = BigInt(18);
        let amount = BigInt(5);
        const tokenABI = [{
                "inputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "constructor"
            },
            {
                "anonymous": false,
                "inputs": [{
                        "indexed": true,
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "owner",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "indexed": true,
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "spender",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "indexed": false,
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Approval",
                "type": "event"
            },
            {
                "anonymous": false,
                "inputs": [{
                        "indexed": true,
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "from",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "indexed": true,
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "to",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "indexed": false,
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Transfer",
                "type": "event"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "owner",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "spender",
                        "type": "address"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "allowance",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "spender",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "amount",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "approve",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "bool",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "account",
                    "type": "address"
                }],
                "name": "balanceOf",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "decimals",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "uint8",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint8"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "spender",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "subtractedValue",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "decreaseAllowance",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "bool",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "spender",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "addedValue",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "increaseAllowance",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "bool",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "name",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "symbol",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "totalSupply",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "recipient",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "amount",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "transfer",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "bool",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            },
            {
                "inputs": [{
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "sender",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "recipient",
                        "type": "address"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "amount",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "transferFrom",
                "outputs": [{
                    "internalType": "bool",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "bool"
                }],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
            }
        ];


        const tokenInstance = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, tokenABI, provider);
        //Do something with this instance here

    }
    
    
</script>
```